# Remover aquivos com o File System

Tags: javascript, node.js, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou tentando remover dois aquivos do meu servidor com o seguinte código:

```
const fs      = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();

app.delete('/delete', function(req, res){
   fs.unlink('path/doc_1', function(){
       fs.unlink('path/doc_2', function(){
           res.end();
       })
   })
})
```

Mas o seguinte erro é lançado:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: O arquivo não está aberto em lugar nenhum?

Comment: Ele não está, eu o salvo no servidor com o 'multer', e uso esse path, para remove-lo

Comment: Muda seu arquivo pra isso aqui e informa o stacktrace completo pf: https://pastebin.com/knbxWyUN

Comment: No exemplo que te passei agora faltou a palavra `async` antes do `(req, res)`

Comment: Cara, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu erro diz que o arquivo está em uso. A sugestão que te dou é fazer a alteração a seguir para que, caso aconteça algum problema fique mais claro para identificá-lo. Com a alteração os arquivos serão deletados paralelamente também:

```
const fs      = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();

const { promisify } = require('util');
const unlink = promisify(fs.unlink);

app.delete('/delete', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Promise.all([unlink('path/doc_1'), unlink('path/doc_2')]);
    res.end();
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send('Ocorreu um erro interno.');
  }
});
```